# Is there a way for me to input css arguments in css height property that are relative to the screen resolution?

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a website and whenever I need to input an image I need to rely on pre-resizing the image, using CSS results in the destruction of the original aspect ratio of the image... So I resize them to fit my screen and later realize that other people have different screen resolutions so my 20 pixels are not their 20 pixels, this leads me to ask whether there is a way to insert images using CSS and resizing it (or any HTML elements in general) relative to the user's resolution...I can resize the pics if a have to...
I am 3 days old to web dev in general... So pls tell me if and where u see a mistake and how to correct it.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the applicable HTML and CSS text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to resize the picture. You can put a reasonable sized image (big enough to be clear, small enough to not take too much space or load slow).

You can use the `vh` and `vw` units to reference a percentage of the viewport's height or width.

So, if you have an image you want to resize, add that styling to make it stretch on the entire screen:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = makefullscreen;

function makefullscreen() {
  document.querySelector('img').classList.toggle('fullscreen');
}
```

```css
img.fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh; /* <-- make the image 100% of the viewport height */
  width: auto; /* <-- match the width based on image aspect ratio */
  /* positioning */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background: #212121;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
<button click="makefullscreen()">toggle image fullscreen</button>
```

Other than this, you can add the same image in multiple sizes to also load the biggest image that matches the resolution. **Notice that this mostly is used to optimize serving the images and not their actual size on the HTML page.**

The trick here is to start with the biggest possible image, or — at least — the biggest image you plan to serve up. Then scale it down to each individual version.

- Largest or original — image-4x.jpg
- Scaled down to 75% — image-3x.jpg
- Scaled down to 50% — image-2x.jpg
- Scaled down to 25% — image-1x.jpg

In order to do this, you need to use `srcset`:

```html
<img
 srcset="
  url size,
  url size,
  url size
 "
 src="default url"
>
```

```html
<img
 srcset="
  /wp-content/uploads/flamingo4x.jpg 4x,
  /wp-content/uploads/flamingo3x.jpg 3x,
  /wp-content/uploads/flamingo2x.jpg 2x,
  /wp-content/uploads/flamingo1x.jpg 1x
 "
 src="/wp-content/uploads/flamingo-fallback.jpg"
>
```

read more about it [here](https://html.com/attributes/img-srcset/)

Comment: Thnx man, u really helped me, I would've upvoted but this is my first Q and i still dont have enough reputation so sorry....

Comment: @mohithalder sure, that's totally fine! I forgot it's something you can't do from the get go :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1** - Relative to screen Size

You can use `vh`- viewport Height & `vw`- viewport Width

example 50% of relative screen height can be written as `50vh` & 50% realtive screen width can be written as `50vw`

Complete Description can be found on this w3school website under the heading **Relative Lengths** [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

**Method 2** - Relative to font size

If in case you wish to use font size as a unit of measurement then there are 2 ways

1. **Relative to element size** where you use `em` here `2em` simply means 2 times the size of the current font
2. **Relative to font-size of the root element** `rem`  this mean "Equal to the computed font-size value on the root element" for example if you have set

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem; /* same as 14px but using rem */
}
```

Comment: thanks mate... still learning so that link really helped me lot

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to just maintain the aspect ratio no matter the width of the img you can use variable for that. By declaring variable in the snippet below it first get the ratio by dividing the actual height by the width of the image. Then you can make the image whatever width you want. The height will be the ratio divided my the width.

In the example below the width is set to 50vw. The height will auto adjust to always maintain the aspect ratio.

```css
:root {
  --ratio: 480/771;
  --width: 50vw; 
  --height: var(--ratio)/var(--width);
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="scene">
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this actually answers the question. OP clearly asked about size relative to the screen resolution. You didn't reference the screen resolution anywhere in your answer

Comment: Too bad you missed the part where I mentioned changing the units to vw. Also he claimed he was having issues with destroying the aspect ratio. This is a great way to not do that.

Comment: It's nice you have a sentence about `vw` and `vh`. but maybe use that in your code snippet for better clarity? Think about the fact that usually the person asking the question is looking for help to understand a topic they're not familiar with. Making the main subject of the question very small compared to everything else might be confusing for someone trying to learn a specific skill. Just trying to help you write better answers. don't take it personally :-)

Comment: Ok changed it to more address the issue